# jQuery can't see an element after its loading via .load()

Tags: html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I load some content into the html page using the jQuery method `.load()` like this:

```
$('#block_name').load('components/content.html #div1');
```

It loads perfectly but I faced an unexpected problem. After that jQuery can't trigger any procedure on elements at the loaded content. For example if `#div1` has the link with id `my_link` then such a calling:

```
$('#my_link').on('click', function(){ /* some actions*/ });
```

has no effect. It looks like it just doesn't exist there although if I try to select it in dev console I can find it. 
Also if I set a handler within that link in the template (content.html) like this:

```
<a id="my_link" href="#" onClick="return myFunction();">Link text</a>
```

...it works perfectly.
So what may be caused for such a problem and is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [.on()'s event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) using:

```
$('#block_name').on('click', '#my_link', function(){ /* some actions*/ });
```

Comment: +1 - That was fast, didn't even have time to finish reading the question ?

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Btw about link you provided. There I have found such an statement: "If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page." Do I understand right that it is equalent to the solution you proposed? It doesn't work :(

Comment: Well yes, you can use event delegation to handle new elements added to a page, or standard event binding added to a page after you have added the new elements to the page.